# Append bash output to vim buffer

Tags: normal-mode

We can execute bash command from vim like this:

```
:! shuf -i1-123124 -n1
```

which generates random number in the given range. Is there a way to append the output to vim buffer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`:read ! shuf -i1-123124 -n1` 
Appending read before the command outputs it to the current buffer

Answer (score 8):

You can use filtering through an external program.
That's not the same as appending though.
In the simplest case, you could replace the current line with the output of `shuf`.

For example, in normal mode, type `!!`, and then `shuf -i1-123124 -n1`. That will replace the current line with the output of `shuf`.

Alternatively, you could replace a specific line with the output of `shuf` with:

```
:123!shuf -i1-123124 -n1
```

Where 123 is the line you want to replace.

For more details and similar operations, see `:help !!`.

Comment: Instead of `123` you can also use `.` to refer to the current line or `$` to refer to the last line. See `:help range`.

Answer (score 4):

`:.! shuf -i1-123124 -n1` (with a dot) does the trick replacing the current line.

`:r! shuf -i1-123124 -n1` creates a new line under cursor position.